# Show executed query in Microsoft SQL Server 2016

Tags: ssms, mysql-workbench, ssms-2016, management-studio-express

In MySQL Workbench, after editing a column, table, or whatever, it will show the query for that action.

I could not find a similar feature in SQL Server 2016. I just want to view the SQL for the action I perform, such as editing a column.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something I've always set is **Auto generate change scripts** which can be found within the options:

[image]

This shows the script and prompts you to save it.

If I don't want it so that every time I do a change it prompts me I use the **Generate Change Script** icon (first icon below):

[image]

This is usually greyed out until you make a modification then you can click it. However the annoying thing is you have to click the icon to generate the script prior to saving the modification.

**Downloaded SSMS 2016**

The icon has slightly changed. In 2016 this is what you are looking for:

[image]

You will want to use the first icon on the toolbar above.

There is also a menu that appears called **Table Designer**. From there you can also generate the change script. This isn't a new feature in 2016 it was something I noticed when looking for the icon.